# Where can I find documentation for notify-osd?

Tags: notification, notify-osd

Whenever something happen which require notification (connecting to a wireless network or low battery status) Ubuntu (unity) gives a nice floating message which (usually) vanishes after several seconds. Is there a way to produce my own floating notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
notify-send "whatever you want to say :)"
```

You can put it in your scripts to notify you about almost anything happens in your system. To see more options like setting title, icons, time, etc...

```
man notify-send
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked out the ubuntu wiki yet?

There's a few examples here
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotificationDevelopmentGuidelines

More general info about it here
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD

Answer (score 0):

Caveat! If using the `Unity` desktop `man notify-send` is contradicted by  [Non-expiring notifications](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/notification/#Non-expiring_notifications)

For details see reference:
https://askubuntu.com/a/189173/89468

The use of `notify-send` is desktop conditioned, depending on whether it is:

1. Unity's notify-OSD
   or
2. Gnome's notification-daemon

that displays the notification.

Quoting  [mhall119/devportal/notify-osd - Ubuntu Wiki:](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/notification/#Non-expiring_notifications)

> `notify-osd`
>
> ... takes the place of `notification-daemon`, and its presentation of
>   notification bubbles differs in several ways ...