# What is the name of the program that displays the notifications?

Tags: notification, notify-osd

What is the name of the program that displays the notifications in ubuntu ? The ones like sound changes, song name (in rhythmbox) etc. Can I send my own custom messages to it ?

quick answer

```
notify-send "Message Title" "The message body is shown here" -i /home/andrei/Pictures/image.png -t 5000
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program is called `notify-osd`, you can use the tool `notify-send` to send messages to it from scripts and your programs and so on:

- [How do I send text messages to the notification bubbles?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108764/how-do-i-send-text-messages-to-the-notification-bubbles)
- [Where can I find documentation for notify-osd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60443/where-can-i-find-documentation-for-notify-osd)

Answer (score 4):

Caveat!

```
    notify-send "Message Title" "The message body is shown here" \
             -i /home/andrei/Pictures/image.png -t 5000
```

is desktop conditioned, depending on whether it is:

1. Unity's notify-OSD
   or
2. Gnome's notification-daemon

that displays the notification.

Quoting  [mhall119/devportal/notify-osd - Ubuntu Wiki:](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/mhall119/devportal/notify-osd#icons)

> `notify-osd`
>
> ... takes the place of `notification-daemon`, and its presentation of
>   notification bubbles differs in several ways ...

In the ubuntu 12.04, Unity (version?) desktop environment, quoting manpage `man notify-send`

```
NAME
       notify-send - a program to send desktop notifications   
   ...
OPTIONS
   ...  
       -t, --expire-time=TIME
              Specifies  the  timeout  in  milliseconds at which to expire the
              notification.
```

however, contradicting it's use by notify-OSD,
quoting from `Notification | Ubuntu App Developer`(`developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/notification/`), specifically section
[Non-expiring_notifications](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/notification/#Non-expiring_notifications):

```
  ...every bubble closes by itself after a timeout. This timeout is based on the
  length of the bubble’s text; Notify OSD does not use the expire_timeout parameter ...
```

The **`-t 5000`** may or may not behave as expected.

ref:
[Where can I find documentation for notify-osd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60443/where-can-i-find-documentation-for-notify-osd)

Bookmark:
[What is the name of the program that displays the notifications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185110/what-is-the-name-of-the-program-that-displays-the-notifications/189173#189173)